# File type inode/x-corrupted

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery, ext4, file-manager

My system had an unexpected shutdown.

Now when I open the file from `pcmanfm` or `nautilus` I get file corrupted error. Strangely the files are accessible just fine if I launch `pcmanfm`as root user. The permissions on the file is `-rw-rw-rw-`

What is happening here?

As user `kshitiz`:

[image]

As root user:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe late but this sometimes happen when nested permissions violate each other.
For example suppose we have this folders structure:

```
Folder1 :
    File1
```

Meaning we have File1 inside Folder1. Now if I set permission for Folder1 as:

```
chmod 444 Folder1
```

and for File1:

```
chmod 777 File1
```

the OS detects a violation and the file manager can't access File1. Because permission of File1 is outside the permitted scope of Folder1.

So check the containing folder and also the file itself.
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem with a flash drive. In order to get it to work I had to set the permissions this way /

```
chmod 771 foldername
```

I hope that this is helpful for you. It was terrible when I thought that the files and folders on my 128GB flashdrive were corrupted.